# How to add the sprites to the PTV Vector map

Tags: ptv-developer

I am trying to run the React PTV tutorial app - https://github.com/PTV-Group/tutorials-vector-map-react-app/tree/master.
And it showns the map fine, but I can't seem to get the sprites to show with the roadsigns etc.?

Running the app as described in https://github.com/PTV-Group/tutorials-vector-map-react-app/tree/master and was expecting that sprites from https://vectormaps-resources.myptv.com/icons/latest/sprite.png was shown on map. But no sprites are shown on map